# How to increment $var value without a loop in PHP?

Tags: php, opencart

I have this issue where i want to increase a value with 1 and apply this to my HTML, but i can't use a `for()` or `while()` loop (at least i think i can't). I'm customizing an e-merchandise program (opencart) and my php knowledge isn't enough to tackle the problem.

There is this function which displays the categories from the store. It uses a variable that is constantly updated via `$var .= "value"`.

I'm so far that i know how many sub-categories there are, but i don't know how to apply this range to my HTML.

I'm working towards a situation like below

```
<ul id="cats">
 <li id="cat1">Cat
  <ul id="sub1">
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="cat2">Cat
  <ul id="sub2">
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I don't have a clue how to increase the count of the *second* unordered lists. Below the code where the second unordered lists are generated.

```
[..]
$cPiD = strlen($parent_id);

if ($results) {
 if ($parent_id == 0) {
  $output .= '<ul id="cats">';
 } else {
  $output .= '<ul id="sub'.$cPiD.'">';
 }
}

[..]
```

The variable `$cPiD` holds the total amount of sub categories (in this case 2). I want this variable to automatically apply the correct number to the unordered list (so apply `id="sub1"` to the first unordered list and `id="sub2"` tot he second one (as in my example above)).

The problem is that i can't use a `for()` loop after the `else` part, because in my HTML i wil get *two* `<ul>` tags instead of one.

Below the PHP code where it all happens

```
$category_id = array_shift($this->path);
$output = '';
$results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($parent_id);
$count = 0;
$cPiD = strlen($parent_id);
```

if ($results) {
 if ($parent_id == 0) {
  $output .= '<ul id="cats">';
 } else {
  $output .= '<ul id="sub'.$cPiD.'">';
 }
}

foreach ($results as $result) {
 $count++;
 if (!$current_path) {
  $new_path = $result['category_id'];
  $output .= '<li id="cat'.$count.'">';
 } else {
  $new_path = $current_path . '_' . $result['category_id'];
  $output .= '<li>';
 }

$children = '';

$children = $this->getCategories($result['category_id'], $new_path);

$output .= $result['name'];

$output .= $children;

if (!$current_path) {
  $output .= '</li>';
 } else {
  $output .= '</li>';
 }

}

if ($results) {
 if ($parent_id == 0) {
  $output .= '</ul>';
 } else {
  $output .= '</ul>';
 }
}

Does anybody maybe have an idea how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
Oh, i tries adding the following construction in the `foreach()` loop, but that gave problems when a certain categories don't have any sub categories.

```
if (!$current_path) {
 $output .= '$result['name'] . ' <ul id="sub'.$count.'">';
}else{
 $output .= $result['name'];
}
```

Comment: Can you check this question for accuracy? It doesn't make sense to me. You state "The variable $pCiD holds the total amount of sub categories", but that variable doesn't exist anywhere. The variable '$cPiD' is the length of a string and nothing more... so can you clarify this, please?

Comment: That was just (for myself) to know how many sub categories exists, i added the variable to maybe clear some things up, but isn't that important i guess..

Comment: what is $current_path set to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
// at the top of your code (ouside of the loop)
$cPiD = 1;
// inside the loop you need to increment the parameter 
$output .= '<ul id="sub'.$cPiD++.'">';
```

After each time the item is used, its value will be incremented by 1. (after already using it)

Comment: If i use this i get two times a 2, instead of first a 1 and then a 2 (both lists get <em>cat2</em> as an id value)

Comment: Makes sence, but when there is a category with no sub categories i get an output like <li><ul id="sub3"></li></ul> (With a missing <li> (or unnecessary </li>))